# Do joins in BigQuery benefit from clustering?

Tags: google-bigquery

[The BigQuery documentation recommends not comparing clustered columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables), the performance of the query is not optimized because block pruning cannot be applied. Example from the documentation:

```
SELECT
  SUM(totalSale)
FROM
  `mydataset.ClusteredSalesData`
WHERE
  customer_id = order_id
```

I take this to mean it will not work with joins (even if their documentation isn't quite doing that).

My question is, does this supersede all other comparisons? What about this:

Example:

```
SELECT table_1.id as ID FROM
  `mydataset.table_1` AS table_1
JOIN `mydataset.table_2` AS table_2
ON table_1.id = table_2.some_property
AND table_1.archived = false   <--------- archived is clustered
```

Will this query benefit from clustering and prune blocks? Or does the join necessitate it scan through all the data no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for joins to benefit from clustering but it is going to be tricky. The join must follow the [fundamental rule of clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#cluster_column_ordering), the column order should be matched.

> The order of clustered columns affects query performance. To benefit from clustering, the query filter order must match the clustered column order and must include at least the first clustered column.

The joining tables should have a parent-child relationship so it can read both tables in the same order and be able to prune the records that don't match the join criteria/ condition. All the data based on the set keys/ filters will always be read when joining clustered tables.